# disable ALL cookie warnings

Tags: users, browser, cookies

What might be an effective way to universally block or auto-accept all cookie warning banners before the web browser shows them?

Eg. Does a userscript (Greasefire/Tampermonkey) exist find and thwart most cookie-warning implementations, perhaps via a regex search? Or at least can this be accomplished with an extention? (Trying not to bloat the browser with yet another extension, though.)

This applies to many outdated UK and EU websites, especially now that the "Cookie Law" is behind us 
http://blog.silktide.com/2013/01/the-stupid-cookie-law-is-dead-at-last/

Comment: I am flagging this question since this site does not deal with implementation based questions.

Comment: Flag away if you must. This time I won't bother procuring a myriad of counter-examples of historical questions. Meanwhile, for those interested in this actual and TIMELY topic: research into "modal overlays" helped a bit. AdBlock Plus, where available, offers some ability to select and ban those annoying overlays, albeit manually and per site.

Comment: I believe, 1) this should be a customer's decision, 2) currently there are no web standards of providing customer's decision to the web server.
Since it's a customer's problem. they should use client software like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiesok/afmkbjoakcacgljcdccofbffloabfbni
As a webmaster, I'll just bother if it works OK on my website and nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't speak to the technical side of your question, you will still get asked as other countries have different laws governing cookies.

Here in Canada it still follows CASL (Canadian Anti-Spam Law) which also discusses use of cookies.

http://fightspam.gc.ca/eic/site/030.nsf/eng/home

Therefore, if you reach any canadian sites, you'll still be asked regarding your acceptance of the use of cookies on that site.